# strtotime returns incorrect timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I work using WAMP on my local machine. If I do `strtotime(1618527600)` it returns false as expected. But whenever I try executing that code on live, it returns an incorrect "timestamp" value of `177675347932`. This only happens on the server, not local.

If you go onto [this website](https://strtotime.co.uk/?str=1618527600) and insert the timestamp in the textfield, it also returns an incorrect "timestamp". If you insert todays timestamp for example, it returns `false` as it should.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: As far as I can see, `false` is returned only for [very old PHP versions](https://3v4l.org/YGHeA). I guess newer versions try to make sense of that number and produce an actual date.

Comment: And here you can see [how it interprets that number](https://3v4l.org/mkU6j).